# invalid_scope error AADSTS70011, Why I am getting this error

Tags: asp.net, oauth-2.0, microsoft-graph-api, office365api

```
public string[] scopes1 = new string[]
{
    "https://graph.microsoft.com/User.Read",
    "https://graph.microsoft.com/User.ReadWrite",
    "https://graph.microsoft.com/User.ReadBasic.All",
    "https://graph.microsoft.com/Mail.Send",
    "https://graph.microsoft.com/Calendars.ReadWrite",
    "https://graph.microsoft.com/Mail.ReadWrite",
    "https://graph.microsoft.com/Files.ReadWrite",

};

public async Task<string> GetAccessToken2()
{
    string url = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?";//https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(url);


        // We want the response to be JSON.
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

        // Build up the data to POST.
        List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> postData = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
        postData.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("grant_type", "client_credentials"));
        postData.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("client_id", appId));
        postData.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("client_secret", appPassword));
        postData.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("response_type", "code"));
        postData.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("response_mode", "query"));
        // postData.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("client_secret", appPassword));               
        //postData.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("client_secret", appPassword));
        postData.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("redirect_uri", "http://localhost/5341/Home/AddC"));
        postData.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Scope",string.Join(" ", scopes1)));// "openid offline_access https://graph.microsoft.com/mail.read"));
        postData.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("state", "12345"));

        FormUrlEncodedContent content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(postData);

        // Post to the Server and parse the response.
        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync("Token", content);
        string jsonString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        object responseData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonString);             

        // return the Access Token.
        return ((dynamic)responseData).access_token;
    }
}
```

> {"error":"invalid_scope","error_description":"AADSTS70011: The
>   provided value for the input parameter 'scope' is not valid. The scope
>   https://graph.microsoft.com/User.Read
>   https://graph.microsoft.com/User.ReadWrite
>   https://graph.microsoft.com/User.ReadBasic.All
>   https://graph.microsoft.com/Mail.Send
>   https://graph.microsoft.com/Calendars.ReadWrite
>   https://graph.microsoft.com/Mail.ReadWrite
>   https://graph.microsoft.com/Files.ReadWrite is not valid.\r\nTrace ID:
>   17e465ac-9aca-4615-8021-f48ee8f00900\r\nCorrelation ID:
>   47a584ed-07ca-4a51-bdd1-8cb7364de3ee\r\nTimestamp: 2017-09-15
>   12:39:26Z","error_codes":[70011],"timestamp":"2017-09-15
>   12:39:26Z","trace_id":"17e465ac-9aca-4615-8021-f48ee8f00900","correlation_id":"47a584ed-07ca-4a51-bdd1-8cb7364de3ee"}

Comment: Can you share `FormUrlEncodedContent content` as a string?

Comment: I would also try using the short scopes, aka "User.Read" instead of "http://microsoft.graph/User.Read"

Comment: I tried that too. and still get the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The call to `https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize` is an  `HTTP GET`, not a `POST`. It is the callback function that takes the authorization code and issues a `POST` to `https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token`.

The prototype for the initial `GET` is (new lines for readability):

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
client_id=[APPLICATION ID]&
response_type=code&
redirect_uri=[REDIRECT URI]&
scope=[SCOPE]
```

The second stage issues a `POST`. That prototype is:

```
POST URL: https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token
POST HEADER: Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
POST BODY: grant_type=authorization_code&code=[AUTHORIZATION CODE]&
           client_id=[APPLICATION ID]&client_secret=[PASSWORD]
           &scope=[SCOPE]&redirect_uri=[REDIRECT URI]
```

Also not that this isn't JSON, the `Content-Type` is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

I wrote an article a while back that walks through the Authorization Code Flow with the v2 Endpoint, you might find it helpful: [Microsoft v2 Endpoint Primer](http://massivescale.com/microsoft-v2-endpoint-primer/)

Comment: Is there any working code sample. As following your stated steps I am able to send first request successfully. but the problem is instead of forwarding me to login page it return html

Comment: I updated the Code. Now the request go properly but instead of returning status code 302 it returns 200 and login page html

Comment: Can you put the new error you're getting into a new question? It relates to a different problem.

Comment: sure I did: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46279377/microsoft-graph-api-oauth-return-status-code-200-instead-of-302-not-redirect-to/46281376#46281376

Answer (score 0):

[https://login.microsoftonline.com/{{tenant_id}}/oauth2/token](https://login.microsoftonline.com/%7B%7Btenant_id%7D%7D/oauth2/token)

remove v2.0 version and try it.
same error code  i have got

> "error_codes": [
> 70011
> ],
> so its resolve your issues