# Microsoft Graph Api OAuth return status code 200 instead of 302 (Not redirect to login Page)

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

To Get Token for Microsoft Graph API. This is the first Call to let authentication user (microsoft) and get code for calling token service.Request properly sent but instead of getting status code 302 so that it can be redirected to login page. I am getting status code 200.

```cs
public async Task<string> GetBToken()
{
    string url = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?"; //https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
    HttpClientHandler clientHandler = new HttpClientHandler();
    clientHandler.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
    clientHandler.AllowAutoRedirect = true;

    using(var client = new HttpClient(clientHandler))
    {
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(url);
        // We want the response to be JSON.
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded"));

        url = url + "grant_type=authorization_code&client_id=" + appId + "resource=https://graph.microsoft.com/ &response_mode=form_post&response_type=code&redirect_uri=http://localhost/5341/Home/AddC &state=12345&scope=" + string.Join(" ", scopes1);

        var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, url);
        var result1 = client.SendAsync(request).Result;

        result1.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

        string jsonString = await result1.Content.ReadAsStringAsync(); // await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        return jsonString;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't execute the OAUTH flow behind the scenes, you need to send the user to `https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?...` directly (i.e. open that URL in a browser).

The process should be:

1. Send user to `https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?...`
2. After authentication, user gets returned to the `redirect_url` you specified. This callback will include query parameters with the Authorization Code you use in #3.
3. Issue a `POST` to `https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token?...`. This will return the Access Token you use when calling Microsoft Graph API.

Comment: Yes, You were right my approach to address the issue was not correct, I follow your suggestion.  Create separte redirect request to authorize link, once recieved the code than using httpclient send request for token. It worked. Thanks a lot

Comment: Hi @Marc
I have same problem. I got same error. I called post url with token URL using Auth Code on response URL. Can you please give me suggestion.