# Converting Resource ID from ADAL to MSAL in Python

Tags: python, azure, token, adal, azure-ad-msal

Our system needs to access resources in `Azure`, and so in our current authentication code we have support for `ADAL` that works well for this purpose.

Now that `MSAL` is replacing `ADAL`, we would like to preemptively add support for it. We are now creating a function that generates an `oauth2` `access_token` using `MSAL` instead of `ADAL`.

We have followed the [migration guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/migrate-python-adal-msal), but there is one issue that we don't find an answer to.

When using `ADAL`, we would supply a `resource_id` containing an ID that would identify the system we are talking about. Usually this `resource_id` was copied from Azure portal.

In `MSAL` there is no `resource_id`, instead we are supposed to use a list of `scopes` instead. If we naively use the existing `resource_id` as a scope like this:

```
resource_id = "XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX"
scopes = [ resource_id ]
```

We get the following error:

```
Error fetching MSAL token (invalid_scope):
    AADSTS70011: The provided request must include a 'scope' input parameter.
    The provided value for the input parameter 'scope' is not valid.
    The scope XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX is not valid.

E   Trace ID: XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX
E   Correlation ID: XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX
E   Timestamp: 2020-03-05 09:36:03Z
```

So the question is, *what is the proper way to prepare a resource ID on the form XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX to a valid scope for `MSAL`*?

**EDIT**: *The answer to this question was tested and used in a small Python package to simplify authenticating with Azure using Requests called [requests_ms_auth](https://github.com/equinor/requests_ms_auth) that is also available as a [pypi package](https://pypi.org/project/requests-ms-auth/)*.

Comment: check this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46239881/invalid-scope-error-aadsts70011-why-i-am-getting-this-error

Comment: @Raghavendra Thanks, but I don't see how it is related? There is no mention in that question about porting resource_id to scope

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `/.default` scope to help migrate your apps from the v1.0 endpoint(adal) to the Microsoft identity platform endpoint(msal). For example, a scope value of `https://graph.microsoft.com/.default` is functionally the same as the v1.0 endpoints `resource=https://graph.microsoft.com`.

```
resource_id = "XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX"
scopes = [ f"{resource_id}/.default" ]
```

Reference:

[The /.default scope](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-permissions-and-consent#the-default-scope)

[Scopes for a Web API accepting v1.0 tokens.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-v1-app-scopes)

Comment: This is fine. But my my scope value is not an URL, it is a resource ID on the form XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX. How can I convert it to an URL? And if I can't convert it, how can I find the URL that matches? That is the real question.

Comment: @LennartRolland You can use scopes = [ resource_id/.default ] Just refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-v1-app-scopes